# Variation of Tower of Hanoi

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have been reviewing the solution of the following problem for which I have to find a recurrence relation for the number of moves:

"In the Tower of Hanoi puzzle, suppose our goal is to transfer all n disks from peg 1 to peg 3, but we cannot move a disk directly between pegs 1 and 3. Each move of a disk must be a move involving peg 2. As usual, we cannot place a disk on top of a smaller disk."

The solution involves the following steps:

1. Move n-1 disks from peg 1 to peg 3 (requires Sn-1 steps)
2. Move the nth disk from peg 1 to peg 2 (requires 1 step)
3. Move n-1 disks from peg 3 to peg 1 (requires Sn-1 steps)
4. Move the nth disk from peg 2 to peg 3 (requires 1 step)
5. Now it takes Sn-1 steps to move the remaining disks from peg 1 to peg 3.

I understand perfectly from 1 to 4 but I do not get the idea of step 5. I will very much appreciate your feedback.

Finally, the recurrence relation is Sn = 3Sn-1 + 2.

Comment: Step 5 is the same as Step 1. We move the stack of $n-1$ disks in $S_{n-1}$ (legal) steps. You should also observe, perhaps, that $S_1= 2$.

Comment: But, it is supposed that peg 2 is a requirement, why does step 5 "suddenly" moves everything from peg 1 to peg 3 without using peg 2?

Comment: @JORGE: It *does* use peg $2$, just as step $1$ does.

Comment: Oh I see, peg 2 is implicitly defined when moving from peg 1 to peg 3 in order to get from 1 to 3 in the correct order of the disks. Am I right?

Comment: @JORGE - yes - that's why I put the "(legal)" in there.

Comment: So you state you have a restriction of going through peg 2, so the disc's can only move 1 step in other words, yet you solve for the puzzle by ignoring this restriction(?). What was the point of this?

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143258/adapted-towers-of-hanoi-from-concrete-mathematics-number-of-arrangements

Answer (score 3):

Step 5 is the same as Step 1. We move the stack of $n−1$ disks in $S_{n−1}$ (legal) steps. This stack move will also use peg 2 in the process, of course, but we don't spell it out as part of this argument. The larger disks below don't affect or interfere with the movement of smaller disks during the stack move.

Thus the recurrence definition of $S_n$ can be established just by adding the number of moves in the 5 steps.

$$S_n =  \overbrace {S_{n-1}}^{\text{step 1}}+\overbrace {1}^{\text{step 2}}+\overbrace {S_{n-1}}^{\text{step 3}}+\overbrace {1}^{\text{step 4}}+\overbrace {S_{n-1}}^{\text{step 5}} = 3S_{n-1}+2$$

You could also observe, perhaps, that $S_1=2$.

Comment: How is it different from basic algorithim? Step 1-:(n-1) moves from peg 1 to peg2.Step 2-:nth disk from peg 1 to peg3 (1 move) step 3-: all n-1 disks from peg2 to peg3 .$H_{n}=2H_{n-1}$+1

Comment: @sourav exactly, that's how it works when movement between peg 1 and peg 3 is permitted, and then $H_1  = 1$.