# Modified tower of hanoi

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

In  the  Tower  of  Hanoi  puzzle ,  suppose  our  goal  is  to  transfer  all  n  disks  from  peg  1  to  peg  3, but we cannot move a
 disk  directly  between  pegs  1  and  3 .  Each  move  of  a  disk
must  be  a   move  involving  peg 2 .  As usual ,  we  cannot
 place  a  disk  on  top  of  a  smaller  disk.

My Attempt/Approach-:

Using Basic Tower of  Hanoi,our goal is to transfer $n$ disks from peg1 to peg2 using peg3.

**Steps-:**

**1.** Transfer  n-1 disks from peg1 to peg3 using $H_{n-1}$.

**2.** Move the $n$th disk from peg1 to peg2 (only 1 movement).

**3.** Transfer n-1 disks from peg3 to peg2 using $H_{n-1}$.

so,We are done with $H_{n}=2H_{n-1}+1$.

**But**,i am not getting how to solve this algorithm using the restriction that " Each move of a disk must be a move involving peg 2." I know the solution to this question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227346/variation-of-tower-of-hanoi),so i am writing steps as i get is

**Steps-:**

**1.** Transfer  n-1 disks from peg1 to peg3 using $H_{n-1}$.

**2.** Move the $n$th disk from peg1 to peg2 (only 1 movement).

**3.** Transfer  n-1 disks from peg3 to peg2 using $H_{n-1}$

giving the same recurrence relation ..where i am wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Recursively transfer $n-1$ disks from peg $1$ to peg $3,$ with every move involving peg $2.$
2. Move the one disk currently on peg $1$ to peg $2.$  (This uses peg $2,$ as required.)
3. Recursively transfer $n-1$ disks from peg $3$ back to peg $1,$ with every move involving peg $2.$
4. Move the one disk currently on peg $2$ to peg $3.$ (This uses peg $2,$ as required.)
5. Recursively transfer $n-1$ disks from peg $1$ to peg $3,$ with every move involving peg $2.$

Of course, when the recursive transfer calls for moving $0$ disks, there's nothing to do (that's the base of the recursion).

Comment: If there would be no restriction then we would have followed the steps as 

**Step1** : move (n-1) disks from peg 1 to peg 2(peg 2 involved ) 

 **Step2** :move $n$th disk from peg 1 to peg 3.

 **Step3** :move n-1 disks from peg 2 to peg 3.

 To save  **Step2** :(no peg 2 involved ) we require 5 steps instead of 3..isn't  it?

Comment: Yes, it takes a *lot*more individual moves to solve the modified version: $3^n-1$ moves, while the original version takes $2^n-1$ moves.