Variant of Tower of Hanoi
The Tower of Hanoi consists of n rings of n different sizes. We move exactly one disk in one step and we cannot place a larger disk on a smaller one. How many steps are there
needed to move the tower from bar A to bar C, if direct moves from A to C (so you need to use B) are
prohibited, but movements in the other direction from rod C to A are allowed?
I'm thinking like this (recursively):

We move n-1 disks to C -> T(n-1) moves
Then the biggest disk goes from A to B -> 1 move
n-1 disks go from C to A -> ??? moves
The biggest disk goes from B to C -> 1 move
n-1 disks go from A to C -> T(n-1) moves

So the solution would be:
T1 = 2
T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 2 + ???
But I don't know how many moves are coming from the third step (n-1 disks from C to A). At first I thought it will be standard Hanoi problem but I think it doesn't work when we want to move at least 4 disks.

I suspect you need to consider all six transitions of a full stack.  Your example is $T_{AC}(n)=T_{AC}(n-1)+1+T_{CA}(n-1)+1+T_{AC}(n-1)$ but $T_{CA}(n)=T_{CB}(n-1)+1+T_{BA}(n-1)$ and similarly for the other four.  You can start with $T_{xy}(0)=0$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1973794/modified-tower-of-hanoi is similar but prohibits both $A \to C$ and $C \to A$
