# Tower of Hanoi variation from Concrete Mathematics - possible arrangements

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics

From Concrete Mathematics, there is a problem that describes a variation of the Towers of Hanoi, where the disks can not move directly from peg $A$ to peg $B$, but must go through a middle peg.  Essentially, you demonstrate that the shortest sequence of moves

$S(n) = 3^n - 1$

I understand this, but the next question asks an extension of this - "Show that, in the process of transferring a tower under (these) restrictions, we will actually encounter every properly stacked arrangement of n disks on $3$ pegs".

The answer given uses a combinatorial approach, indicating that there are $3^n$ possible arrangements of $n$ disks on three pegs (each disk could be on each of three pegs), and since the process involves $3^n - 1$ moves, you must encounter each of these arrangements.  This is where my question lies - in those $3^n-1$ moves, there are multiple times where you have the same arrangement (for instance, if you are moving $2$ disks, there are $2$ times when the smallest disk is by itself on the middle peg).  This seems to indicate to me that saying that you have $3^n-1$ moves does NOT necessarily mean you hit $3^n$ DIFFERENT arrangements.

I think I'm missing something...

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143258/adapted-towers-of-hanoi-from-concrete-mathematics-number-of-arrangements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had exactly the same configuration twice (That is all three pegs identical), you have a loop wich can be left out. This contradicts the minimality of $3^n - 1$ moves.

Comment: Oh yes, of course - that makes sense.  I think I was thinking about just one disk at a time, rather than each move really being a snapshot of a different arrangement of disks on all three pegs. I was thinking of two steps where disk 2 is on the middle peg as being the same because disk 2 was in the same position, but I was forgetting that at each step the occupants of the other pegs were different.